# Monthly rolling window summation from daily data of many companies price in r

Tags: r

I want to calculate 11 months summation in rolling window basis by using daily data. The data frame is like this. I have 17 years daily data with more than 300 companies in this file

```
head(Rolling_window)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
        date price1 price2 price3 price4
      <dttm>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2000-01-04  72.27   6.63   2.38   2.98
2 2000-01-06  72.27   6.63   2.39   2.98
3 2000-01-11  72.27   6.63   2.41   2.98
4 2000-01-12  69.00   6.63   2.41   2.98
5 2000-01-13  68.67   6.63   2.41   2.98
6 2000-01-14  69.60   6.63   2.41   2.98
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right , you can use this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

date <- c('2000-01-04','2000-01-06','2000-01-11','2000-01-12',
          '2000-01-13','2000-01-14','2000-02-14','2001-02-14')
n <- NROW(date)
df <- tibble(date,price1 = rnorm(n),price2 = rnorm(n,0.1),price3 = rnorm(n,10),price4 = rnorm(n,5))
df %>% 
  mutate(date = as.character(date)) %>% 
  separate('date',c('year','month','day')) %>% 
  group_by(year,month) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(price1, price2, price3, price4),funs(mean)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

**UPDATE FOR SPEED UP**

I rewrite code using `data.table` package, now it will work much faster:

```
require(data.table)

df <- as.data.table(df)
df_sum <- df[, c('year','month','day') := tstrsplit(date, "-", fixed=TRUE)
             ][
               ,c('date','day'):=NULL,
               ][
                 , lapply(.SD, mean), by = list(year,month)
                 ][
                   , rollapply(.SD,11,sum,partial = T),
                     .SDcols=c('price1','price2','price3','price4')
                    ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. Putting so many dates in code is difficult. Is there any alternative solution to avoid that. @Alex

Comment: You mean, that it computationally difficult to operate with so much dates?

Comment: Since I have to write all these 17 years daily date in r script. It would be time consuming

Comment: Okey, I see. So, I recommend you rewrite this script using data table. This will be much more faster, then using dplyr approach. Or you can wait a little bit, and I rewrite by myself

Comment: Ok I am waiting for your rewrite. Thank you so much

Comment: Done.Ttry to check it.

Comment: Rolling sum meaning the summation of first 11 month´s value (Jan 2000 to Nov 2000) and than second  11 month´s value (Feb 2000 to Dec 2000) and so on. Your output showing something diffrent

Comment: Yes,you right. I add just one line of code to do roll sum, I forgot about it, sorry.

Comment: showing this error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158072/discussion-between-alex-and-syed-riaz-mahmood-ali).

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code for one go

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
dummy = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2017-12-31"),"day"),
                   price1 = sample(5.5:9.5,731,replace = T),
                   price2 = sample(5.5:9.5,731,replace = T),
                   price3 = sample(5.5:9.5,731,replace = T),stringsAsFactors = F)

dummy_rolling_11m = dummy %>% mutate(yearmonth = as.yearmon(Date)) %>% 
  select(-Date)%>% group_by(yearmonth) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(.,na.rm = T))) %>% 
  arrange(yearmonth) %>% select(-yearmonth) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(rollapplyr(.,11,sum,partial = T)))
```

Comment: Plenty of errors like :Error in library(zoo) : there is no package called ‘zoo’, Error in library(lubridate) : there is no package called ‘lubridate’, Error in data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-04"), as.Date("2017-08-31"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6450, 731

Comment: Please install the required packages!! using `install.packages(c("zoo","lubridate"),dep = T)`

Comment: Error in data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-04"), as.Date("2017-08-31"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6450, 731

Comment: I created dummy data for sake of reproducible example, am not sure why you are doing that part of code as you already have your data, if you still want to resolve the error you just shown above, paste line of code in comment

Comment: Ok I understand, sorrry for that. Now it is working.